# AWS amplify push/pull error: "error pulling the backend environment dev"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am trying to configure my react native app to work with aws amplify. I installed aws and configured the amplify cli. I ran the following commands:

`amplify configure`
`amplify init`
`amplify add api`

```
"Authorization modes: API key (default, expiration time: 7 days from now)
 Conflict detection (required for DataStore): Disabled"
```

I do get an error of
`There was an error adding the API resource.`

But when I perform `amplify status`, it shows that my api has been added.

```
┌──────────┬────────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Category │ Resource name  │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │
├──────────┼────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ calorieexpoapp │ Create    │ awscloudformation │
```

Then I get an error when I `amplify push`
Error:

```
- Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the cloud.
× There was an error pulling the backend environment dev.
 The specified key does not exist.
```

So from my aws console in the browswer, I see that my app has been created and linked to the cloud. But no apis have been added according to the aws console.
[image]